# Can I run python scripts as regular commands in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, python, script

I have some utilities scripts written in Python. Is it possible to configure **Windows 10** so that I could run those scripts as regular commands? For example I have an utility script that iterates over directories and calculates total duration of all media files inside the directories. Currently in order to run the script I should navigate to the folder with the script and run `python calculate-duration.py --arguments`. Instead I would like to be able to run it as a regular command `calculate-duration --arguments`. Is it possible to configure Windows such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file called `calculate-duration.bat` and set its contents
as:

```
cd folder-with-script
python calculate-duration.py --arguments %*
```

Add a path to the python command (if not already in the PATH).
Ensure that the batch file is inside a folder that is in the PATH.

You have now added a `calculate-duration` command.

Note that `%*` means to copy all the arguments on the call to the
batch script.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that when you install Python on Windows you can also install "Python Launcher". This should automatically setup Python Launcher as the Windows default EXE for file `.py` file extensions.

This works in a similar way that double click for say `.txt` is (normally) handled by `Notepad.exe`. Confirm the mapping by right mouse on any ".py" or ".pyc" file, choose `Properties` and note the "Opens with:" application name - it should say "Python" here.

Once correctly mapped, double-clicking any `.py` file in Window Explorer will run it in Python, or typing `xyz.py {args}` in command prompt kicks off python without need to type in `python xyz.py {args}`.